# Where do I find all the artifacts?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm trying to collect all the artifacts in Stardew Valley, but I'm missing a number of them. I seem to have exhausted the supply of new artifacts from worms (the ones you dig up with a hoe), as I keep getting ones I've already seen. Where else do I find artifacts? I've gotten a few from treasure chests while fishing; is that a source I'm missing? Where else can they be found?

I occasionally find them in geodes, but I've broken a ton of geodes open and haven't had much luck there (I get minerals more than I get artifacts).

Comment: Have you explored the mines and skull cavern?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right, you're missing other ways to get new artifacts. According to [Stardew Valley Wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Artifacts), artifacts can be acquired in the following ways:

- Using the Hoe on worm tiles. Different parts of the map will drop different artifacts. These locations are much more common in winter.
- Using a Hoe on dirt located within The Mines and Skull Cavern.
- Killing Monsters.
- Fishing for treasure chests.

In case you want a list with the artifacts and their locations, see below or refer to this [page](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Artifacts):

Dwarf Scroll I

```
Mines level 1-105 (maybe every level, not confirmed)
Green Slime (Secret Woods)
```

Dwarf Scroll II

```
Mines level 40-65
Blue Slime (Secret Woods)
```

Dwarf Scroll III

```
Mines level 40+
Lava Bat (Mines Level 81+)
Blue Slime (Secret Woods)
Skull Cavern
```

Dwarf Scroll IV

```
Any Monster (Mines)
Using hoe on dirt (Mines level 81+)
```

Chipped Amphora

```
Town (4%)
```

Arrowhead

```
Mountain (2%)
Forest (2%)
Bus Stop (2%)
```

Ancient Doll

```
Mountain (4%)
Forest (3%)
Bus Stop (3%)
Town (1%)
Fishing Chest (Ocean/Secret Woods)
```

Elvish Jewelry

```
Forest (1%)
Fishing Chest (?%)
```

Chewing Stick

```
Mountain (2%)
Forest (2%)
Town (1%)
Fishing Chest (?%)
```

Ornamental Fan

```
Beach (2%)
Forest (1%)
Town (0.8%)
Fishing Chest (River)
```

Dinosaur Egg

```
Mine (1%)
Mountain (0.8%)
Fishing chest (Ocean/River)
```

Rare Disc

```
Underground Mine (1%)
Fishing Chest (Ocean/River)
```

Ancient Sword

```
Forest (1%)
Mountain (0.8%)
Fishing Chest (Ocean/River)
```

Rusty Spoon

```
Town (5%)
Fishing Chest (River ?%)
```

Rusty Spur

```
Farm (10%)
Fishing Chest (River ?%)
```

Rusty Cog

```
Mountain (5%)
Mine ~14 in dirt
Fishing Chest (Ocean/River)
```

Chicken Statue

```
Farm (10%)
Fishing Chest (?%)
```

Ancient Seed

```
Forest (1%)
Mountain (1%)
Fishing Chest (River)
```

Prehistoric Tool

```
Bus Stop (4%)
Mountain (3%)
Forest (3%)
Fishing Chest (?%)
```

Dried Starfish

```
Beach (10%)
Fishing Chest (River ?%)
```

Anchor

```
Beach (5%)
Fishing Chest (?%)
```

Glass Shards

```
Beach (10%)
Fishing Chest (Ocean)
```

Bone Flute

```
Underground Mine (2%)
Mountain (1%)
Forest (1%)
Town (0.5%)
Fishing Chest (River)
```

Prehistoric Handaxe

```
Mountain (5%)
Forest (5%)
Bus Stop (5%)
```

Dwarvish Helm

```
Underground Mine (1%)
```

Dwarf Gadget

```
Underground Mine (0.1%)
```

Ancient Drum

```
Underground Mine (2%)
Bus Stop (1%)
Forest (1%)
Town (0.5%)
```

Golden Mask

```
Desert (4%)
```

Golden Relic

```
Desert (8%)
```

Strange Doll 1

```
Everywhere (0.1%)
Fishing Chest (?%)
```

Strange Doll 2

```
Everywhere (0.1%)
Fishing Chest (?%)
```

Prehistoric Scapula

```
Town (1%)
Forest (?%)
```

Prehistoric Tibia

```
Forest (1%)
Railroad (?%)
```

Prehistoric Skull

```
Mountain (1%)
```

Skeletal Hand

```
Beach (1%)
```

Prehistoric Rib

```
Town (1%)
```

Prehistoric Vertebra

```
Bus Stop (1%)
```

Skeletal Tail

```
Underground Mine (1%)
Fishing Chest
```

Nautilus Fossil

```
Beach (3%)
Fishing Chest (Ocean/River)
```

Amphibian Fossil

```
Forest (1%)
Mountain (1%)
Fishing Chest (Ocean)
```

Palm Fossil

```
Forest (1%)
Beach (1%)
Desert (1%)
```

Trilobite

```
Forest (3%)
Beach (3%)
Mountain (3%)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's more on worm tiles

- a worm tile's drop is the same drop per day every time you reload the game
- some worm tiles don't despawn the next day

With these two elements, all you have to do is

- wake up
- look for these worm tiles and dig them
- if you haven't found anything interesting, just reload the game and redo your day as normal
- the next day, wake up and repeat the first steps

The problem is that some artifacts are **very** rare and this method will work hardly on seasons other than winter. The solution (yes it's cheating) is to change your save game file to put more worm tiles in a zone!

- **BACKUP YOUR SAVE GAME FILE** (%appdata%/stardewvalley) This is very important because when you close the game it might upload a corrupted filegame in the steam cloud!
- go to the beach and look for an artifact spot, it must be surrounded by sand (no rocks, shells,...)
- open your save file and search for "beach", it must be in a `<gamelocation>` xml tag

  ```
  <GameLocation xsi:type="Beach">
  ```
- slowly search further for "Artifact spot", once you have one, copy somewhere else all the text including the `<item>` tags

  ```
  <item>
      <key>
          <Vector2>
              <X>38</X><Y>10</Y>
          </Vector2>
      </key>
      <value>
          <Object>
              <specialVariable>0</specialVariable>
              <category>0</category>
              <specialItem>false</specialItem>
              <hasBeenInInventory>false</hasBeenInInventory>
              <Name>Artifact Spot</Name>
              <Stack>1</Stack>
              <tileLocation>
                  <X>38</X><Y>10</Y>
              </tileLocation>
              <parentSheetIndex>590</parentSheetIndex>
              <owner>0</owner>
              <name>Artifact Spot</name>
              <type>asdf</type>
              <canBeSetDown>true</canBeSetDown>
              <canBeGrabbed>true</canBeGrabbed>
              <isHoedirt>false</isHoedirt>
              <isSpawnedObject>false</isSpawnedObject>
              <questItem>false</questItem>
              <isOn>true</isOn>
              <fragility>0</fragility>
              <price>0</price>
              <edibility>-300</edibility>
              <stack>1</stack>
              <quality>0</quality>
              <bigCraftable>false</bigCraftable>
              <setOutdoors>false</setOutdoors>
              <setIndoors>false</setIndoors>
              <readyForHarvest>false</readyForHarvest>
              <showNextIndex>false</showNextIndex>
              <flipped>true</flipped>
              <hasBeenPickedUpByFarmer>false</hasBeenPickedUpByFarmer>
              <isRecipe>false</isRecipe>
              <isLamp>false</isLamp>
              <minutesUntilReady>0</minutesUntilReady>
              <boundingBox>
                  <X>2432</X><Y>640</Y>
                  <Width>64</Width>
                  <Height>64</Height>
                  <Location>
                      <X>2432</X><Y>640</Y>
                  </Location>
              </boundingBox>
              <scale>
                  <X>0</X><Y>0</Y>
              </scale>
          </Object>
      </value>
  </item>
  ```
- you can now duplicate this item block by changing the X Y coordinates near the initial worm tile. For the values of the bounding box you must do a simple division (in my case, 640 / 10 => 64) to find this number and adapt it to new coordinates
- put the new item blocks next to the one you found in the save game (that you have backuped of course)
- load the game
- dig
- ????
- ARTIFACTS!!